# MySQL and PHP - Password Compare

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a stored procedure to check the username and password on login attempts. - The passwords are stored using the password() function in MySQL.

And the login works fine, using the stored procedure, the problem is that I have a function that enables the user to change the password, how should I update it? as MD5 through PHP? or should I build a new stored procedure?

Thanks :)

Comment: “[Note: The `PASSWORD()` function is used by the authentication system in MySQL Server; you should *not* use it in your own applications.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password)” But don’t use the mentioned `MD5()` or `SHA2()` either, use a [proper password derivation function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/401656/53114).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to use the PASSWORD() function for your application-level passwords.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password says:

> Note
>   The `PASSWORD()` function is used by the authentication system in
>   MySQL Server; you should not use it in your own applications. For that
>   purpose, consider `MD5()` or `SHA2()` instead. Also see RFC 2195, section
>   2 (Challenge-Response Authentication Mechanism (CRAM)), for more
>   information about handling passwords and authentication securely in
>   your applications.

If you use a standard cryptographic hash method like SHA2, you can perform the hashing in PHP, using the [hash extension](http://php.net/hash). Hashes calculated with the same algorithm in PHP are compatible with those calculated in MySQL.

Comment: Also, don't use a single round algorithm like `md5` or `sha1`. [Read this](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/) on how to safely store a password.